# Promotions and conversions of variables in printf()

Tags: c, implicit-conversion, integer-promotion

In this case,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char a = 1;
    printf("%hhu", -a);

    return 0;
}
```

The argument `-a` in `printf` is promoted to `int` by the integer promotion by the unary minus operator and subsequently promoted by the default argument promotion and finally converted to `unsigned char` by the format specifier.
So `-a` => `-(int)a`(by `~`) => no conversion by function call => `(unsigned char)-(int)a`(by `%hhu`). Is my thought right?

Comment: The C standard is not entirely clear on the conversion by `%hhu`. While it says the `int` value passed to `printf` is converted to `unsigned char` (or `signed char`, but that is for `%hhd`, but the language in the standard conflates them), it also says the value passed in that `int` shall be an `unsigned char` value. Since `-a` will not have an `unsigned char` value if `a` is not zero, one could regard this as failing to pass a value meeting the requirement, and therefore the resulting behavior is not stated by the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf` is a variadic function. The type of the arguments passed by `...` parameter are not known inside the function. As such, any variadic function must rely on other mechanisms to interpret the type of the `va_arg`s arguments. `printf` and family use a `const char* format` string to "tell them" what kind of arguments were passed. Passing a type different then the expected type as specified by it's format specifier results in Undefined Behavior.

For instance:

```
printf("%f", 24)
```

Is undefined behavior. There is no conversion from `int` to `float` anywhere because the arguments are passed as they are (after promotion) and inside the `printf` the function incorrectly treats its first argument as `float`. `printf` does not know and can't know that the real type of the argument is `int`.

Variadic arguments undergo some promotions of their own. Of interest for your question `unsigned char` is promoted to `int` or `unsigned int` (I am not sure tbo). As such there is no way for a variadic parameter to actually be of type `unsigned char`. So `hhu` while is indeed the specifier for `unsigned char` it will actually expect an `unsigned int` (`int`), which is what you pass to it.

So afaik the code is safe because of the two integer promotions caused by unary minus and passing variadic arguments. I am not 100% sure though. Integer promotions are weird and complicated.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that `a` is promoted to `int` in `-a`, and that `printf("%hhu", -a);` passes an `int` to `printf`. The notional conversion performed with `%hhu` is not clear.

Note that if `a` is not zero, then `-a` produces a value (in an `int`) that is not an `unsigned char` value. Further, with two’s complement eight-bit `signed char`, if `a` is greater than 128, then `-a` produces a value that is not a `signed char` value.

To understand `%hhu`, we look at the specification for `u` in C 2018 7.21.6.1 8:

> The `unsigned int` argument is converted to unsigned octal (o), unsigned decimal (u),…

and for `hh` in 7.21.6.1 7:

> Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a `signed char` or `unsigned char` argument (the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to `signed char` or `unsigned char` before printing);…

First we have to resolve this issue of “`signed char` **or** `unsigned char`”. Does this say we can pass either a `signed char` or an `unsigned char` for `%hhu`? I think not; I think the authors have just put together the language for `%hhd` (intended to convert a `signed char`) and `%hhu` (intended to convert an `unsigned char`). So I believe the intent is that a promoted `unsigned char` should be passed for the `%hhu` conversion specification.

Apple Clang 11.0.0 seems to agree, when passing `-a` (but not `a`), it warns: “warning: format specifies type 'unsigned char' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]”

As noted above, passing `-a` may pass a value that cannot result from passing a promoted `unsigned char`. It may even pass a value that cannot result from passing a promoted `signed char` or `unsigned char`. In this case, it can be argued we have violated the requirement to pass an `unsigned char`, and therefore the C standard does not specify the resulting behavior. Even though it says the passed value shall be converted to an `unsigned char`, I believe that is a notional conversion, not a specific requirement on the library implementation, and that is also falls under the “as if” rules: It does not actually have to be performed if the resulting defined behavior of programs is the same. But, since passing an improper value may not be defined, we do not have defined behavior.

That may be a strict reading of the rules, but it would not surprise me greatly if `printf` printed “4294967295” instead of “255” when `a` were 1.