# Printf performing implicit casting

Tags: c, printf, unsigned-char, conversion-specifier

In the below code snippet, why do we get an output of 600? Two questions will help me understand the behavior.

1. I specified the type for variable *b* to be *uint8_t*, why doesn't the math operation restrict to the same type?
2. I thought *PRIu8* is the right type to print uint8_t, why isn't this working?

I was hoping to get the answer 88 which results from looping beyond the range of uint8_t

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void main()
{

    uint8_t b = 200;
    printf("%" PRIu8 "\n",b+b+b);
    printf("%" PRIu8 "\n",3*b);

}
```

gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)

Comment: There surely be a dupe, somewhere, but please read about [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion), in particular integer promotion and the usual arithmetic conversions. If you want the result to be an `uint8_t`, you need a cast: https://godbolt.org/z/rjxejqrEb

Comment: This is due to default argument promotions.

Comment: As mentioned by others, there are implicit conversions (e.g.) your `b` will be converted to `int` or `unsigned int`. You can get the expected result with: `printf("%u\n",(uint8_t) (b+b+b));

Comment: @Bob__ I searched for "default integer promotion printf", but couldn't find a good dupe for this.

Comment: @niil87 MS Visual Studio outputs 88.

Comment: @Barmar Well, there's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65770931/promotions-and-conversions-of-variables-in-printf), which is close.

Comment: @Bob__ That's one of the ones I saw. I didn't think signed/unsigned was close enough to 8-bit/32-bit.

Comment: BTW, it should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: @Bob__ Thank you for the feedback.. didn't realize this was important!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844915/what-happens-if-main-does-not-return-an-int-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it is a library bug.

In MS Visual Studio the macro `PRIu8` is expanded to `hhu` as it should be and you get the expected result.

It is interesting to note that if to use clang then if you will write for example

```
printf("%" PRIu8 "\n",( uint8_t)(b+b+b));
```

when again you will get the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

In C, whenever you call a function with elipsis (`...`) arguments, such as printf, all of those arguments will undergo *default argument promotions*.  This means that any smaller integer type will be converted to `int` and passed that way.  So in printf, `h` type prefixes are irrelevant -- they'll be ignored by printf and have no effect (as the argument must be an `int` anyways).

In addition, the same conversion of smaller integer types will happen for any arithmetic operator (like `+` or `*`) and the resulting operation will be carried out with `int` precision, giving an `int` result.

To get the expected result, explicitly mask it to the appropriate size:

```
printf("%u\n", (b+b+b) & 0xff);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, what are h type prefixes?

Answer (score 0):

If we take a look at inttypes.h, we find the following:

```
# define PRIu8      "u"
```

So this format specifier doesn't contain any length modifier.  This makes sense in the context of its corresponding argument, as it's impossible to pass a `uint8_t` to a variadic function.  Because this type has a smaller rank than `int`, a value of this type will get promoted to `int`.  This promotion also happens in the expressions `b+b+b` and `3*b`.

If you explicitly use a length modifier for a `char`, you'll get the expected result.

```
printf("%hhd\n",b+b+b);
printf("%hhd\n",3*b);
```

Comment: It looks like a library bug,

Comment: @VladfromMoscow For me, it is too. I would expect to have it printed correctly.